# Add Storyboards/Trickplay using either WebVTTT or JSON using Exo player

Tags: android, exoplayer, mux-video

I am trying to implement Video thumbnail while seeking the seek bar using MUX(https://docs.mux.com/docs/storyboard-guide) in exo-player but unable to find the sample for it so did any one implement it or is there any other way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

The thumbnails you see when you scan a video are generally generated on the server side and are a set of images in a separate track in the video container, rather than generated in real time by the player.

The manifest will typically include a pointer to the thumbnail track.

Many packages can be configured to generate one thumbnail per iFrame for your stream.

Comment: Is there any way to extract thumbnail from Video for any specific position while seeking seekbar?

Comment: Its certainly technically possible - the problem is you need to decode the video at whatever point your seeker is hovering over to display the nearest frame, and this is time and processor consuming for anything but very small videos and so may not lead to a great user experience, especially on low powered devices.

Comment: Yes you are right. Actually I found one solution and it showing thumbnail properly but we have to use Mux image and it's has different structure that's why it doesn't load thumbnail properly. so I was thinking to extract thumbnail from URL (.m3u8 or mp4). This worked for me
https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/MI201109210084_1/thumbnails/f08e80da-bf1d-4e3d-8899-f0f6155f6efa.jpg using third party code but not for Mux one